# In Rails 3, I'm getting a NoMethodError for the recycle! method during testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixtures, functional-testing, recycle

I've got a functional test that's using fixtures. I also am using fixtures in my Unit tests, but they work without flaw. When running the functional tests, I get a:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'recycle!' for #<Response:0x10346be10>
  /test/functional/responses_controller_test.rb:10:in 'test_testing'`

My **functional tests**, at this point, are doing nothing more than a get to the index action. Example:

```
setup do
  @response = responses(:one)
end

test "testing" do
  get :index
  assert true
end
```

My TestHelper class does include all fixtures, so the Responses fixtures are definitely loading. And like I said, the fixtures work perfectly fine in Unit tests.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Change

```
setup do
  @response = responses(:one)
end
```

to

```
setup do
  @myresponse = responses(:one)
end
```

and off you go!

The problem lies in "actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb" around line 386.

The testcase assumes that @response holds a "ActionDispatch::Response". You overwrite it, it's no "ActionDispatch::Response" anymore and the testcase fails.

I'm not sure if this is intended behaviour.

Anyway, just make sure you don't overwrite @response/@request/@controller/@routes and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, just saved my bacon. Had a similar issue with a variable called @request.

Comment: Wow! Had exactly the same code as the OP, and now I have exactly the same code as your solution! @flo

Answer (score 2):

Flo's answer is mostly correct, but I just wanted to clarify:

In Rails 3.0.x that @request is expected to be an `ActionController::TestRequest` type, which has the `recycle!` method defined on it.  There's `TestResponse`, `TestRequest`, and `TestSession`.

You might want to actually initialize or manipulate objects of these types for certain situations.  In my case, I needed to mock the site having a specific domain name with

```
@request = ActionController::TestRequest.new unless @request
@request.host = "www.hostname.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar problem naming a variable `@request`.
I changed to `@_request` and it solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks. The same holds true with `@response`.